# No me muestra los repetidos SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

mi problema es el siguiente

necesite traer todos los montos repetidos  de esa Codigo de cuenta

yo lo pense asi, pero no me trae nada

Alguna idea?

mi query:

```
SELECT
    TransaccionId,AccountCode,Cuentas.Description,
    NetAmount, CreatedDate,
    DocumentType,
    nombreApellido_usuario,
    DATENAME(DAY,EffectiveDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,EffectiveDate)+ ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,EffectiveDate) as fecha,
    JournalDescription,
    LineDescription,
    Movimiento.Descripcion,
    TiposComprobante.codigo_comprobante
FROM TablaPrincipal
    LEFT JOIN Usuarios ON TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
    LEFT JOIN Cuentas ON TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta
    LEFT JOIN Movimiento ON TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento
    LEFT JOIN TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante
WHERE AccountCode = 1113006
GROUP BY
    TransaccionId,
    AccountCode,
    Cuentas.Description,
    NetAmount,
    CreatedDate,
    DocumentType,
    nombreApellido_usuario,
    JournalDescription,
    LineDescription,
    Movimiento.Descripcion,
    TiposComprobante.codigo_comprobante,
    EffectiveDate
HAVING COUNT(NetAmount) >= 2
```

Comment: o alguna idea ? sin usar el group by

Comment: qué resultado obtienes si quitas 'having COUNT (NetAmount)>=2'?

Comment: me trae todos lo montos!

Comment: PAra que haces semejante cantidad de joins, si solo queres los repetidos por cuenta? busca primero los repetidos por cuenta.. y despues hace todos los joins que queres.

Comment: Fui haciendo eso! pero no me trae nada cuando agrupo lineDescription y JournalDescription ( por que tiene valores distintos esos campos) por eso no me funciona el group by

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales sobre qué datos estás ejecutando tu query para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos posibles soluciones, dependiendo de que necesites.

Un query sencillo que simplemente te diga cuantas veces esta cada monto:

```
 SELECT NetAmount, COUNT(TransaccionId) FROM TablaPrincipal WHERE AccountCode = 1113006
 GROUP BY NetAmount
```

y la otra es hacer tu consulta con todos tus campos y agregarle una subconsulta que te diga cuantas veces aparece ese monto:

```
 SELECT
TransaccionId,AccountCode,Cuentas.Description,
NetAmount, CreatedDate,
DocumentType,
nombreApellido_usuario,
DATENAME(DAY,EffectiveDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,EffectiveDate)+ ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,EffectiveDate) as fecha,
JournalDescription,
LineDescription,
Movimiento.Descripcion,
TiposComprobante.codigo_comprobante
 --SubConsulta:
(SELECT COUNT(TransaccionId) FROM TablaPrincipal X WHERE X.NetAmount = NetAmount)
---
 FROM TablaPrincipal
LEFT JOIN Usuarios ON TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
LEFT JOIN Cuentas ON TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta
LEFT JOIN Movimiento ON TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento
LEFT JOIN TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante
```

WHERE AccountCode = 1113006
GROUP BY
    TransaccionId,
    AccountCode,
    Cuentas.Description,
    NetAmount,
    CreatedDate,
    DocumentType,
    nombreApellido_usuario,
    JournalDescription,
    LineDescription,
    Movimiento.Descripcion,
    TiposComprobante.codigo_comprobante,
    EffectiveDate
HAVING COUNT(NetAmount) >= 2

en estas consultas estoy asumiendo que los campos NetAmount y TransaccionId son de la tabla TablaPrincipal

Espero te sirva